# What is the difference between a matrix and image in Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, matrix, png

I can save a .png image as `pic = imread(image_name)` and I can treat it as a matrix including the size so that I can retrieve `[nrows, ncols, ~] = size(pic)`. I can then easily show this image with `imshow(pic)`.

However, if I create my own matrix with `test = zeros(nrows, ncols, 3)` and try to copy over the image with `test(:, :, :) = pic` and try to use `imshow(test)` it doesn't work. I can compare `test` and `pic` element by element and they are the same, but I can't subtract the two or I get an error of

```
Error using  - 
Integers can only be combined with integers of the same class, or scalar doubles.
```

How can I create a matrix and assign pixels from an image to it and still treat the matrix as an image? The reason I am trying to do this is that I have many pictures I am trying to combine into one larger picture, so I need to create a large matrix beforehand, then copy pixels from each seperate image into the larger matrix, but this larger matrix is no longer treated as an image when I use `imshow` or `imwrite`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error is telling you the thing that you miss. It is the [`class`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/classes-in-the-matlab-language.html) of the variable that matters. an image has some class type (uint8, uint16...), a generic matrix in matlab, unless stated otherwise is `double`. Try to define

```
 test = zeros(size(pic),class(pic));
```